# correct mean vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

Can you please tell me how you can correct mean vector in Matlab if such thing exists?

Say I have this vector:
`x= 60.44 70.7 80.3 90 100 90.445 40.50 50.21 30 66.7`

I am not talking about taking a mean of a vector which can be done using `mean(x)`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple correction for mean:

```
x-mean(x)
```